# What version of Google's protobuf builds with -std=c++98 or -std=c++03?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I'm building software for an embedded system that only has a cross compiler for -std=c++98. We want to send data encoded via protobuf 2 to a server. Unfortunately protobuf now requires C++11.

In https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/2780 it's suggested that "We may create a branch that works for C++98. The branch will only accept bug fixes, but not new features, optimization, etc"

https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/3492 "Code should compile with --std=c++03 before we switch to c++11 only" has been closed, but I can't find the corresponding commit.

I've tried to build a few versions with -std=c++98 and -std=c++03 but always get "error: use of undeclared identifier 'va_copy'" which is specific to c++11 and later.

Can anyone advise which version (if any) builds with -std=c++98 or -std=c++03?

If this isn't possible I could fall back on https://github.com/nanopb/nanopb which is an ANSI C implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [v 3.5.0](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.5.0). The release after 3.5.0 has a strict C++11 requirement, 3.5.0 shouldn't have this.

Comment: I tried using 3.5.1 https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.5.1 because that has some bug fixes and removes some C++11 remnants from 3.5.0, but this version still has the va_copy problem