# What version of GRPC can I use to build with c++98 for WinCE?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, grpc, windows-ce, c++98

I would like to build [GRPC](https://github.com/grpc/grpc) for WinCE with the c++98 std. What is the last Version where it is working? Is there one?

I heared, that [Google Protobuf](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf)s last version for c++98 is the [v3.5.1](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.5.1) is that [correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56899336/what-version-of-googles-protobuf-builds-with-std-c98-or-std-c03)?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

From the issue [protobuf/2780](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/2780), It is mentioned that they decided to move on from C++98 to C++11 in the version gRPC 4.x. Back then they did not have a major release,  therefore it was 1.4.x. This was September 2017. Corresponding release is also in late v1.3.x and early 1.4.x, so, at least anything gRPC <1.3.9 should be compatible with C++98.

> I heared, that Google Protobufs last version for c++98 is the v3.5.1 is that correct?

Yes, that is also correct according to the mentioned issue.